# SQL Server 2019 Insert Performance: CentOS 7 vs Windows 10

Tags: performance, windows-10, sql-insert, centos7, sql-server-2019

We have a small sample export (~100k rows) of a database. The format is a .sql file with Insert statements in each row:

```
Set Identity_Insert dbtable ON
Insert into dbtable (Id,Name) values(1,N'dummy');
... repeated 1k rows
Set Identity_Insert dbtable OFF
GO
```

Apart from this not being the best practice for exporting/importing, we observed major performance differences between SQL Server 2019 running on Linux (CentOS 7) vs. running on Windows 10. Both SQL Servers were freshly setup with the latest installer and used out of the box, so no particular settings or optimizations done.

```
Time for 100k Inserts
CentOS 7: ~330 seconds
Windows 10: ~17 seconds
```

Regarding the compute power, the CentOS system should be way more powerful, running on a HPC cluster with 16 cores, 32 GB memory and high bandwidth storage cluster. The Windows system is a typical office Laptop (i7, 16 GB, SSD).

Any ideas where to start troubleshooting? Are there major differences in the base installation / default setup of SQL Server between the different OS?

Comment: Try wrapping the inserts in a large transaction. I suspect slow log IO (over 1ms) on the server's storage subsystem.

Comment: Not enough info here, but it's **very** common for so-called high-performance storage to be misconfigured such that it's a bottleneck. You also have to be deliberate about your memory configuration; make sure the CentOS installation is actually able to make use of all the memory.

Comment: Almost certainly slow log IO, due to the need to flush because no transaction, and to top it off, probably Windows not recognizing it is an SSD and therefore not flushing properly. Either way, this is most definitely not the best way to insert 100k rows

Comment: Thank you all very much for the comments. I will look into storage IO performance and transaction insert.

Comment: @DanGuzman Following your comment, I wrapped the inserts into large transactions. This results in a speedup to ~5 seconds execution time on the Windows machine. More importantly it only takes ~7 seconds on the CentOS system to complete, which is more than fine for the current application. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @HenningFrechen, glad it helped. I expanded on my comment with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each insert is a separate autocommit transaction by default. SQL Server will flush the transaction log buffer to disk after every insert to harden the transaction. The time it takes for these physical writes (100K in this case) will vary greatly depending on IOPS capabilities of the storage subsystem. It is not uncommon that Local SSD, even on a PC, might outperform enterprise grade SAN storage for a sequential write IOPS workload because SAN latency is higher than a local PCI bus.

Batching the inserts in large transactions will reduce the number of physical transaction log writes and speed up the insert script considerably.